# Add own program to Panel Applets

Tags: raspbian, python, cpanel

I have a small python program that prints the temperature every second.

How can I add this program as a Plugin to my Panel?

I can see that in the file `~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panels/panel` there are entries for Plugins looking like

```
Plugin {
  type=ejecter
  Config {
  }
}
```

So, where are these plugins, and how can I add my own program?

Comment: Why not add the existing temperature applet? Right click on task bar,'Panel Settings','Panel Applets' tab,'Add',select 'Temperature Monitor',click 'Add'

Comment: Because that was just an example I chose. It's the process of adding own programs to the panel what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% clear to me precisely which of several closely related options you're trying to achieve but the answer here from Unix & Linux SE seems like it would be one way to use your program from a panel: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318610/146316